# Using FindViewById<> returns null when trying to get the BottomNavigationView

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a custom renderer for my GradientTabbedPage, and I'm trying to set a gradient background to the BottomNavigationView, but each Resource Id I try to use ends up with it returning null.

```
public class GradientTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer
{
    public GradientTabbedPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context) { }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TabbedPage> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        var control = (GradientTabbedPage)Element;

        var tabs = FindViewById<BottomNavigationView>(Resource.Id.bottomtab_tabbar);
        if (tabs == null) return;

        tabs.SetBackground(new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.LeftRight,
            new int[] { control.TopColor.ToAndroid(), control.BottomColor.ToAndroid() }));
    }
}
```

I have tried the following Resource.Ids:

```
bottomtab_tabbar
bottomtab_navarea
bottom
main_tablayout
```

I don't understand why Android has to make it so difficult to expose different elements in the way that iOS seems to. I'm new to renderers, but from what I can see, iOS does it much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could help you

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TabbedPage> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        var control = (GradientTabbedPage)Element;

        var gradientDrawable = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.LeftRight,
            new int[] { control.TopColor.ToAndroid(), control.BottomColor.ToAndroid() });

        var relativeLayout = this.GetChildAt(0) as Android.Widget.RelativeLayout;
        var bottomNavigationView = relativeLayout.GetChildAt(1) as BottomNavigationView;
        bottomNavigationView.SetBackground(gradientDrawable);
        bottomNavigationView.Elevation = 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue from what I can see is that you are not using the correct Context.

What needs to be understood first is that every activity sets layout as a content view and it has its living cycle.

I suppose you use this class GradientTabbedPageRenderer somewhere in some activity(I name it here YourHolderActivity). To reach its elements you need to provide its context or the activity itself.

How to fix it:

1. Pass the activity in the constructor of the class
2. Find the view by activity context

---

```
public class GradientTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer
{
    public YourHolderActivity _yourHolderActivity;
    
    public GradientTabbedPageRenderer(YourHolderActivity yourHolderActivity, Context context) : base(context) 
    {
        _yourHolderActivity = yourHolderActivity;
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TabbedPage> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        var control = (GradientTabbedPage)Element;

        var tabs = _yourHolderActivity.FindViewById<BottomNavigationView>(Resource.Id.bottomtab_tabbar);
        if (tabs == null) return;

        tabs.SetBackground(new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.LeftRight,
            new int[] { control.TopColor.ToAndroid(), control.BottomColor.ToAndroid() }));
    }
}
```